# Check entire array for single if operation

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have this code to check some input data to be sure it fits a proper format. However input_28 is a list field that is sent as an array. Is there a shortcut to check each item in the array for the filter instead of looping through each item?

I dont care what it wrong or which line does not match. I just need to know if any line does not match the filter so I can return the form with an error.

`if($_POST['input_28'] != filter_var($_POST['input_28'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=> "/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)|()/" )))){`

Comment: Could you please be a bit clearer on the question? Are you wanting to check if POST input is an array?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether the POST input is in an array? - PHP's `in_array()` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php or whether the POST input is an array? `is_array()` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: Neither I need to check if each item in the POST array matches the filter. and continue if anyone does not match. I only need to return once for the entire array. So if the first one is wrong I dont need to check the rest. i added detail to the question

Comment: You could for example use array_reduce, array_filter or array_walk for that. However, with a simple loop over the array you have the advantage that you can break out of the loop easily the first time the check on an element fails.

Comment: preg_grep I think will actually work nicely. With the Preg_grep_invert option. So correct me if I am wrong, if I use `$input-28=preg_grep("/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)|()/", $_POST['input_28'], preg_grep_invert)` and then `if(count($input-28) > 0)` that should return true if any of the array does NOT match the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for `array_search()`, you can use it like this

```
if(array_search($value, $array)){
// Do stuff
}
```

Note that `array_search()` only works if the array is NOT multi-dimensional, you can take a look on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) for more references and examples

Comment: That would work except for the filter_var function I am using. I am basically filtering the input with the regex expression. Then compare the output of that to the original input. As long as they match the format is correct. It would not work with the array_search because $value would need to change for each item in the array. If not for the complex regex testing this would work great. Is there any way to make $value a regex expression?

Answer (score 0):

Some searching on functions that @Alfonso mentioned in his answer led me to another function: `preg_grep` That led to this little function which worked great.

```
      $input_28=preg_grep("/^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)$/", $_POST['input_28'], PREG_GREP_INVERT);
        if(count($input_28) > 0){
           #Do Something
        }
```

The `PREG_GREP_INVERT` makes it return an array of entries that do NOT match the filter. Then we count the array, if any did not match the array will have an entry. Thus greater than `0`